# I keep getting the error "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'"

Tags: python

I am relatively new to programming. I got an error message

```
    if int(row[c + 1]) != (small_res[c]):
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'
```

I do not understand how that relates to my code. Any help pointing in the right direction would be appreciated

```
if len(argv) != 3:
    print("Usage: python dna.py data.csv 
sequence.txt")
    exit(1)
database = open(argv[1])
sequence = open(argv[2])

read = csv.reader(database)
text = sequence.read()
reader = next(read, None)

rept_ttttttc = 0
rept_tctc = 0
rept_agatc = 0
rept_ta = 0
rept_aat = 0
rept_gat = 0
rept_gaa = 0
rept_tctg = 0
rept_tctag = 0

small = [rept_agatc,rept_aat,rept_ta]
small_res = list(map(int, small))
large = [rept_agatc,rept_ttttttc,rept_aat,rept_tctag,rept_gat,rept_ta,rept_gaa,rept_tctg]
large_res = list(map(int,large))

#with open(sys.argv[1], newline='') as 
csvfile:
#reader = 
csv.reader(csvfile)#csv.DictReader(csvfile) 
#delimiter=",")
#next(reader)

#with open(sys.argv[2], 'r') as f:
#text = f.read()

pattern = re.compile(r'(AGATC)+')
matches = pattern.finditer(text)
for match in matches:


    longest =  match.end() - match.start()

    rept_agatc = longest/ len('AGATC')

pattern1 = re.compile(r'(TTTTTTCT)+')
matches1 = pattern1.finditer(text)
for match in matches1:

    longest1 = match.end() - match.start()
    rept_ttttttc = longest1 / len('TTTTTTCT')

pattern2 = re.compile(r'(TATC)+')
matches2 = pattern2.finditer(text)

for match in matches2:

    longest2 = match.end() - match.start()
    rept_ta = longest2 / len('TATC')

pattern3 = re.compile(r'(AATG)+')
matches3 = pattern3.finditer(text)
for match in matches3:
    longest3 = match.end() - match.start()
    rept_aat = longest3 / len('AATG')

pattern4 = re.compile(r'(GATA)+')
matches4 = pattern4.finditer(text)
for match in matches4:
    longest4 = match.end() - match.start()
    rept_gat = longest4 / len('GATA')

pattern5 = re.compile(r'(GAAA)+')
matches5 = pattern5.finditer(text)
for match in matches5:
    longest5 =  match.end() - match.start()
    rept_gaa = longest5 / len('GAAA')

pattern6 = re.compile(r'(TCTG)+')
matches6 = pattern6.finditer(text)
for match in matches6:
    longest6 = match.end() - match.start()
    rept_tctg = longest6 / len('TCTG')

pattern7 = re.compile(r'(TCTAG)+')
matches7 = pattern7.finditer(text)
for match in matches7:
    longest7 = match.end() - match.start()
    rept_tctag = longest7 / len('TCTAG')


found = False
for row in reader:
    for c in range(len(small)):
        if int(row[c + 1]) != (small_res[c]):
        #if int(row[c+1]) != 
int(small[c]):
            break
        elif c == (len(small)-1):
        #elif c == (len(small) -1):

            print(row[0])
            found = True
            break

    for b in range(len(large)):
        if int(row[b+1]) != int(large[b]):
            break
        elif b == (len(large) - 1):

            print(row[0])
            found = True
            break

    if found == False:
        print("No match")
        exit(0)
```

Comment: The error tells you how it relates to your code: it tells you exactly which line the error occurs on.  : `if int(row[c + 1]) != (small_res[c])`.  So `row[c + 1]` is apparently equal to 'a', which cannot be converted to an integer.

Comment: I understand that, it how it is not an integer that I can't see, I tried changing that to int but that did not work, so i am lost

Comment: oh, I think i understand

Comment: Add a debug print: `print(c, row[c+1])` just before that line. Also `print (len (row))` before the inner loop could help.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Check out the [tour] and [ask]. Debugging questions require a [mre], but `data.csv` is missing (among other things), and there's a lot of code here seems to be irrelevant to the problem. You can [edit] the question.

Comment: "I don't understand how it relates to my code." Well, you have a line of code that reads `if int(row[c + 1]) != (small_res[c]):`. So that's the line it's complaining about. It says that `'a'` is an `invalid literal for int()`. So the problem is what you pass to `int`. What do you pass to `int`? That is `row[c+1]`. The error message tells you that `row[c+1]` is equal to `'a'`. Were you expecting `row[c+1]` to be equal to `'a'`? Or were you expecting `int('a')` to produce a meaningful value? Or just what?

Comment: @Sander Where did you get those from? The error message says `int(row[c + 1])` is the problem.

Comment: Thank you all for the feedback, the for loop is suppose to read through a file that has integer values. I did some debug print suggested by Roberto. I was calling the wrong file thats where the confusion came from! I cant believe I did not see that in the first place and because the file name was similar I could not see my mistake!